# How to write software to read/write to USB device

Tags: windows, usb

We have this USB device that we would like to communicate with. This specific device is listed in the Windows device manager as a 'USB Composite Device'. The details reveal that it has the following driver stack:

- \Driver\usbccgp
- \Driver\USBPcap
- \Driver\USBHUB3

I also took a look with UsbView. This reveals that it is a CDC device. It has 2 interfaces
The first:

```
    bInterfaceNumber:                  0x00
    bAlternateSetting:                 0x00
    bNumEndpoints:                     0x01
    bInterfaceClass:                   0x02  -> This is Communications (CDC Control) USB Device Interface Class
    bInterfaceSubClass:                0x02
    bInterfaceProtocol:                0xFF
    iInterface:                        0x05
         English (United States)  "RNDIS Communications Control"
      -> This is a Communications (CDC Control) USB Device Interface Class
```

The second:

```
    bInterfaceNumber:                  0x01
    bAlternateSetting:                 0x00
    bNumEndpoints:                     0x02
    bInterfaceClass:                   0x0A  -> This is a CDC Data USB Device Interface Class
    bInterfaceSubClass:                0x00
    bInterfaceProtocol:                0x00
    iInterface:                        0x06
         English (United States)  "RNDIS Ethernet Data"
```

It is not a virtual serial port though; that would be too easy.

My goal is to first find the device, then retrieve information about it, and then send data to it and read data back from it.
It took me some time and I have achieved the first two goals. The source code of UsbView was of great help. But now I have much trouble with the last part.
For example, I have looked at this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/how-to-write-a-windows-desktop-app-that-communicates-with-a-usb-device
With this help I can now find the device and open it with the `CreateFile` function. But then it fails at the `WinUsb_Initialize` function. Probably because it is a composite device, right? But what else can i do?

Comment: you might want to look at `pyserial` https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: "not a virtual serial port ". No, the `iInterface` suggests it is a virtual Ethernet port. That means the USB device appears as a LAN. To communicate with it, you'd just open a plain old socket.

Comment: MSalters, you are correct. I can see the device in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections

Comment: As the USB device implements a standardized USB protocol (for virtual Ethernet), Windows grabs it, installs standard device drviers and adds a network connection. Using Zadig, you can replace the driver with WinUSB and then access it with WinUSB functions. For a single computer, that's straightforward. If it should work on many computers, it's not practical.